# CSS cursor:pointer; won't work

Tags: css, cursor

I checked other answers and didn't find any solution.

I'm not sure why the cursor won't show a poiner on .plantoggle elements.

I have this on my CSS:

```
.plantoggle{
    padding:23px 40px 24px;
    font-weight:400;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#999;
    margin-top:5px !important;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1rbf5v3a/

Thank you.

Comment: It is working for me in your example. You still get the regular cursor? What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Works in IE11, newest Chrome and Firefox... Some Mac browser, or Edge, probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the weirdest thing that happened to me in a long time.

I was working on Chrome on OS X El Capitan when I had this issue.

I also tried Firefox and still got the same issue so I asked the question.

@Bastiaan told me that it works on his side in his comment.

So I restarted my Mac and the problem is gone.

Not sure what caused this.

Comment: How can it be a cache issue when the same issue is on all browsers?